# Can I use a boot usb as a storage device as well in windows

Tags: windows, usb, partitioning, storage, boot-partition

I recently bought a 32gb usb 3 drive and made it a bootable usb. there is about 25gb of unallocated space, which i formatted to ntfs, however windows only recognises the boot partition as it is the first partition on the drive. is there any way to swap them around so the 25gb is available for storage, whilst also remaining a boot disc should I need it?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked in Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc) if the 25gb partition is assigned a drive letter correctly.

I have a similar key setup as you, 10gb boot and ~120gb data space which gets letters U & V accordingly - I'm using usbdlm to control the USB drive letter assignments.

Comment: yeah, the manager wont let me assign a drive letter, as the boot partition already has one, which i cant remove (no option to), so it says windows will not recognise it and will not let me :/ I can however make it a primary partition without the drive letter, but i dont think a logical partition would work, would it?

Comment: I should have been a bit more specific in previous answer. Windows by default does not allow multiple partitions on drives marked as removable - to achieve that you'll need a filter driver called cfadisk.inf which in turn must be updated with your USB device ID (can be found via Device Manager under details, set property to Hardware IDs and copy the first line)
cfa filter driver > http://www.etcwiki.org/dl/USB_LocalDisk.zip
64 bit version > http://uploaded.to/file/1nbepp7r
Once you have modified the inf file, load the new driver for the USB drive and you're good to go...